# Как в классе инициализировать public переменную?

Tags: php

Вопрос неоднозначный но поясню:

Имеется класс:

```
class Config {

    public function __construct($config = '') {
        ...
    }

}
```

Мне нужно в конструкторе этого класса инициализировать public переменную этого класса (которая, в свою очередь тоже будет экземпляром этого класса) т.е. в результате такого действа:

```
$config = new Config('custom');
```

Получился объект $config класса Config с такой структурой (прошу прощения за псевдоязык):

```
$config = Object(Config) {

    public $custom = Object(Config) {

        public function __construct($config = '') {
            ...
        }

    }

    public function __construct($config = '') {
            ...
    }

}
```

Хочу сделать такую вот рекурсию в конструкторе образования класса.

Пытаюсь реализовать паттерн MVC. Фреймверки не использую т.к. уже работал с таковыми и считаю полезным (в плане опыта, осмысления ООП) написать что-то на чистом PHP. В ходе написания понадобилось грузить конфиг, который разбит на несколько файлов в виде такой структуры:

```
application
|_config
| |_database.php
| |_session.php
|_system
| |_core.php
|_и т.д.
```

Файлы конфигурации представляют из себя ассоциативные массивы, т.е. так:

```
session.php:
$session['prefix'] = 'PP_';
```

Хотелось бы в любом месте программы иметь простой доступ к конфигу, т.е. так:

```
echo $config->session->prefix;
```

или так:

```
echo $config->session->get('prefix');
```

Comment: Ок, с этим разобрался, похоже, что так:

$this->$config = new Config();

А что, если нужно инициализировать private переменную?

Comment: Что бы инициализировать private переменную, нужно использовать setter.


`class A{
  private $var;
  public function setVar($value){
    $this->var = $value;
    return $this;
  }
  public function getVar(){
    return $this->var;
  }
}
$A = new A();
echo $A->setVar("var")->getVar();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Пытаюсь реализовать паттерн MVC. Фреймверки не использую т.к. уже
> работал с таковыми и считаю полезным
> (в плане опыта, осмысления ООП)
> написать что-то на чистом PHP. В ходе
> написания понадобилось грузить конфиг,
> разбитый на несколько файлов в виде
> такой структуры:
>     application |_config | |_database.php | |_session.php
> |_system |_core.php 
>     Файлы конфигурации представляют из себя массивы, т.е. так: 
>     session.php: $session['prefix'] = 'PP_';
>     Хотелось бы в любом месте программы иметь простой доступ к
> конфигу, т.е. так: 
>     $config->session->prefix или так: $config->session->get('prefix')

Для решения вашей задачи, я бы посоветовал реализовать паттерн [Registry](http://alexmuz.ru/php-registry/), он прекрасно впишется в вашу архитектуру.

P.S.: по ссылке, в конце обзора паттерна даже есть такая вещь:

> На основе этого класса можно создать
> класс Config, для хранения различных
> параметров проекта.
>
> ```
> <?php
> class Config extends Regisrty
> {
>   // Дополнительные методы 
> }
> ?>
> ```